# Sending multiple documents to a mongo collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

so i have a collection of forms that users sends I generate a match when some criteria is meet between 2 forms now i'd like to send the match information to a MongoDB collection but when trying it sends empty information.

I tried the next code with different variations but it doesnt seems to work, all it does in send an object with an ID and nothing else.

```
const newMatch = new Match(matches)
newMatch.save()
```

Extended example:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Forms = require("../models/Forms");
const Match = require("../models/Match");

const matchMaker = {
    generateMatch: async (req, res) => {

    let data;
    let ignore = [];
    try {
      data = await Forms.find();
      const result1 = findMatches1(data);
      const result2 = findMatches2(data);
      const result3 = findMatches3(data);
      
      if (result1.length >= result2.length && result1.length >= result3.length) {
        res.json(result1);
      } else if (result2.length >= result1.length && result2.length >= result3.length) {
        res.json(result2);
      } else if (result3.length >= result1.length && result3.length >= result2.length) {
        res.json(result3);
      }
      function findMatches1(data) {
        data.sort((a, b) => a.time.length - b.time.length);
      
        const matchedIds = new Set(); 
        const matches = []; 

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
          if (matchedIds.has(data[i]._id)) continue; 
      
          const person1 = data[i];
          const options1 = person1.time;
      
          for (let j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++) {
            if (matchedIds.has(data[j]._id)) continue; 
      
            const person2 = data[j];
            const options2 = person2.time;
      
            if (
              person1.date === person2.date &&
              person1.place === person2.place &&
              person1.modality === person2.modality
            ) {

              const commonTime = options1.find((time) => options2.includes(time));
      
              if (commonTime) {
                matches.push({
                  participant1: person1.firstName + ` ` + person1.surname,
                  participant2: person2.firstName + ` ` + person2.surname,
                  date: person1.date,
                  time: commonTime,
                  modality: person1.modality,
                  place: person1.place,
                  status: person1.status,
                  organization: person1.organization
                });
                matchedIds.add(person1._id);
                matchedIds.add(person2._id);

                const newMatch = new Match (matches)   
                newMatch.save()

                break; 
               
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return matches;
      }
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const MatchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  participant1: {
    type: String,
  },
  participant2: {
    type: String,
  },
  date: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  time: {
    type: String,
  },
  modality: {
    type: String,
  },
  place: {
    type: String,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
  },
  organization: {
    type: String,
  }
});

const MatchModel = mongoose.model("matchs", MatchSchema);

module.exports = MatchModel;
```

Thank you for any insight you can provide

Comment: what is the schema for `Match` collection  ?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log("matches", matches)` before `const newMatch = new Match (matches)` ?

Comment: @SrushtiShah it generates the match and shows the correct data but mongo just get 
{"_id":{"$oid":"646b09b3be709316bba0c8bb"},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}

Comment: You are savig the matches after breaking the loop.

Comment: @SrushtiShah thank you for your answer, changed it before the break but its giving the same result

Comment: Try debugging, put `consile.log("before newMatch", matches)` above `const newMatch = new Match (matches)` and another under `for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {` like `console.log("under for loop")`, So that you can cetermine that whether `newMatch` console executes before for loop or not, If so then you need to use promises